# Simple API endpoint app running on Google Cloud never receives req.body

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, endpoint

I have an api running on the google cloud. This is an example endpoint

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) =>{
  if (!req.body){
    return res.json({code: 500,msg: 'no body', time: Date() })
  }
  return res.json({code: 500,msg: req.body, time: Date() })

})
```

Testing it locally, no problem. Using postman, simple raw body of JSON for the request.

```
{
    "msg" : "hello",

}
```

This works locally, I know the code is correct. But when its running on the cloud, the body is always empty when I send it. I have tried to track down all the details for allowing http/https traffic to access it, but it seems I am still missing something. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What Google Cloud service are your running this on? Post your entire code and not just the post function body.

Comment: It is just a tiny test. It is running on an ubuntu16.04 server, deployed with Nodejs8. I can fire it up and hit the endpoint, just nothing I do will send the body with the POST request. I have the server set to allow all http/https and all ports, so as far as I can tell there should be nothing restricting the data passing to it. I have found a few other articles that details the same issues, but no good answers yet.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am quite sure the issue is in the deployment, I think perhaps I took a few too many shortcuts to get it up and running. I am taking a more pragmatic approach, following through the steps of deployment using the gcloud cli. I think that may solve things. Thank you for your help.